# Public Dictionary - how to access data

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up a public dictionary in VBA on Workbook_Open(). I would like to access the items in this dictionary in any module that I create in the spreadsheet.

My code in `ThisWorkbook` is:

```
Option Explicit
Public Dic As Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set Dic = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dic.Add Key:="cat", item:="Database"
    Dic.Add Key:="pwd", item:="Password"
    Dic.Add Key:="col", item:="Server"  
End Sub
```

When I go to any module and use the `msgbox` function to call an item, it does not work:

```
MsgBox (Dic("col"))
```

Any tips please how to make this work?

The idea is to set up this dictionary right at the beginning of the spreadsheet and access it is required in any of the subsequent modules.

Cheers

Comment: Hey @Tom, No. I created a new module and done this:Option Explicit
`Option Private Module
Public Function test()
MsgBox (Dic("col"))
End Function`

Comment: Move `Public Dic As Scripting.Dictionary` to the declarations area (aka top) of a public module.

Comment: @Jeeped - I am confused. Sorry. Do you mean I have to declare Dic again in any module that I use it on? I thought I can only do it once on ThisWorkbook and have it as a global dictionary. Sorry mate, confused...

Comment: No, take it out of the ThisWorkbook private code sheet and put it into **one** public module code sheet.

Comment: @Jeeped - I see where I went wrong. Many thanks man. Wanna add it to answer and I will mark it correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see that you have made the 'public' declaration of the *Dic* scripting dictionary in the private ThisWorkbook code sheet. This makes it available to any sub procedure within the private ThisWorkbook code sheet.

To make it available to any sub procedure in any code sheet, put it in the declarations area (i.e. the top) of any one public module code sheet. This will allow you to still populate the dictionary object from the private Workbook_Open and retain the populated values to be used anywhere in the project.

[image]